# вывод многомерного массива

Tags: php

Как вывести с таким видом, чтобы было

Название области: город, город, город

```
$cities = [
    'Московская область' => [ 
        'Москва', 
        'Зеленоград',
        'Клин'
    ],
    'Иркутская область' => [
        'Иркутск',
        'Ангарск',
        'Братск',
        'Железногорск-Илимский'
    ],
    'Красноярский край' => [
        'Красноярск',
        'Артёмовск',
        'Енисейск'
    ]
];

foreach ($cities as $reg => $city) { 
    foreach ($city as $city_val) {
        echo("$reg: $city_val");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `implode`:

```
$cities = [
    'Московская область' => [ 
        'Москва', 
        'Зеленоград',
        'Клин'
    ],
    'Иркутская область' => [
        'Иркутск',
        'Ангарск',
        'Братск',
        'Железногорск-Илимский'
    ],
    'Красноярский край' => [
        'Красноярск',
        'Артёмовск',
        'Енисейск'
    ]
];

foreach ($cities as $reg => $list) { 
  echo $reg, ':  ', implode(', ', $list), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Тогда уж лучше так: ```array_walk($cities, function($v, $k) {echo "$k: ", implode(', ', $v), PHP_EOL;});```

Comment: @gregzakharov, В чём по вашему разница между циклом и вызовом array_walk?